# Non-Overlapping corner box-shadow

Tags: css

How would you create non-overlapping box-shadows in the example below?

As SO wants me to give more details: Your goal is to create box-shadows for the elements `.top` and `.side` without changing the markup (if possible) that do not overlap.

Edit: Both box-shadows must have blur-radius >0.

Edit 2: "Non-overlapping" means in this case that both shadows will not drop into the other element.

Edit 3: See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEgYA.jpg) awesome picture for further explanation.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25k5z7eq/4/)

**Code:**

```css
.wrapper-all {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.wrapper-side {
  margin-left: -50px;
  left: 50px;
}
.top {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
h2,
p {
  text-indent: 15px;
}
.side {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-all">
  <div class="wrapper-side">
    <div class="side"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-top">
    <div class="top">
      <p>My shadow is overlapping on the left. Not cool.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>Have a nice day! :)</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Both which elements? There are many.

Comment: Elements are named now. thanks

Comment: `.side { z-index: 10 }` ?

Comment: .side { z-index: 10 } will not prevent the `.side` shadow from overlapping

Comment: is it what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/oy9fvdfo/  ? or you need just to slightly shift .top to the right?

Comment: @Jekyll can you give us a picture of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: will give picture

Comment: @Banzay no, i want non-overlapping shadows

Comment: here is a blur radius >0 : https://jsfiddle.net/9jko3f0z/

Comment: @Banzay works, thank you very much. You may want to post it as answer so i can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just to expand a shadow and make a blur as a part of shadow itself, so blurring won't be visible out of another sides of blocks. For that you need to define spread radius (4th parameter of shadow), which positive values increase the size of the shadow, negative values decrease the size. Default is 0 (the shadow is same size as blur):

```css
.wrapper-all {
  padding-left:50px;
}
.wrapper-side {
  margin-left: -50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.top {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 7px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 7px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  box-shadow: 2px 7px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
h2, p {
  text-indent: 15px;
}
.side {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  box-shadow: 7px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-all">
  <div class="wrapper-side">
    <div class="side">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-top">
    <div class="top">
    <p>
    My shadow is overlapping on the left. Not cool.
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>
   Have a nice day! :)
  </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right I think this is what you want?
Just remove the position: relative of top div..

```css
.wrapper-all {
  padding-left:50px;
}
.wrapper-side {
  margin-left: -50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.top {

  background-color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
h2, p {
  text-indent: 15px;
}
.side {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-all">
  <div class="wrapper-side">
    <div class="side">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-top">
    <div class="top">
    <p>
    My shadow is overlapping on the left. Not cool.
    </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question says blur-radius >0. With blur, it does still overlap :(

Comment: The first 2 values are not blur that is offset.

Comment: correct, but you use `box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);` on `.top` and ` box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);` on `.side`. Adding blur will make them overlap.

Comment: Do you or do you not want blur or just not overlap and have a blur?

Comment: Why that? The given solution just doesnt use blur, thats it! Go and check out the fiddle with `box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);` on `.top` and `box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);` on `.side`.

Comment: Like the question says, I want blur on both shadows and those shadows shall not overlap.

Comment: Then just delete the position on the top div. Look at update

Comment: I cant see any difference, `.side` shadow does still overlap. Working code was alrady provided in comments above, thank you very much though :)

Answer (score -1):

I was also in this trouble, and I solved it with this ugly hack:

```
.top {
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.top:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff; /*same as side bg*/
}
```

Edit:
https://jsfiddle.net/kantoci/25k5z7eq/5/